# What does the sign ' | ' mean in java?

Tags: java

I have come across the code and I am wondering what does it do?

```
for(int i=1;i<32;i++){

    for(int j=1;j<32;j++){

        if(( i | j )==31){ // here the sing ' | '

         }
     }
  }
```

Comment: It's a [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

Comment: Ok thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'|' is a bitwise operator in java.

You'll find a decent explanation here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Not to be confused with '||' which means or.

Comment: Better suited as a comment.